# Merging 2 branches together in Git

Tags: git, merge, commit

I've only just started to use Git and think it is wonderful, however I'm a little confused over what the `merge` command does.

Let us say we have a working project in the branch "A".

I go home and make changes to this branch and save it as "B".
Another programmer makes changes to "A" and saves it as "C".

Is there a way to merge the two branches "B" and "C" together, then commit the changes as a new branch, say "D"?

Or am missing the point of 'merge'?

Comment: no need to 'save changes' in another branch. work an A and then merge those different A's together

Comment: I don't follow. A would be on my local computer, dev1 would have a copy of A on his computer, and dev2 has a copy of A on his computer. Both devs make changes, how do i merge these changes together?

Comment: see <http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html>. the devs probably need to push/upload their repository somewhere first

Answer (score 315, accepted):

`merge` is used to bring two (or more) branches together.

A little example:

```
$ # on branch A:
$ # create new branch B
$ git checkout -b B
$ # hack hack
$ git commit -am "commit on branch B"

$ # create new branch C from A
$ git checkout -b C A
$ # hack hack
$ git commit -am "commit on branch C"

$ # go back to branch A
$ git checkout A
$ # hack hack
$ git commit -am "commit on branch A"
```

So now there are three separate branches (namely A B and C) with different heads.

To get the changes from B and C back to A, checkout A (already done in this example) and then use the merge command:

```
$ # create an octopus merge
$ git merge B C
```

Your history will then look something like this:

```
…-o-o-x-------A
      |\     /|
      | B---/ |
       \     /
        C---/
```

If you want to merge across repository/computer borders, have a look at `git pull` command, e.g. from the PC with branch A (this example will create two new commits):

```
$ # pull branch B
$ git pull ssh://host/… B
$ # pull branch C
$ git pull ssh://host/… C
```

Comment: that means that both branches did change the same piece of code. fix up the conflitcs, `git add conflicting_files` and then `git commit`

Comment: Say the file in A contained the word "hello", the A amended it to "HELLO" and B amended it to "Hello world". What would be the outcome of merging these files?

Comment: Whoops, i mean B amended it and C amended it.

Comment: be careful with the word 'amend' that means something different in git (changing existing commits). changing a file 'hello' to 'HELLO' on one side and 'Hello World' on the other side will result in a merge conflict

Comment: @dotty: While git often *seems* like magic, it can't actually read your mind - if two branches make two different changes to the same content, only a human can figure out how to reconcile them. That's what a merge conflict is.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Some issues I ran into which I have posted as well. but other than that it was perfec.

Comment: Wow, that history looks like [GitLab Tanuki](https://about.gitlab.com/images/new_logo/B.jpg)!

Comment: Man, It's not only useful but I also liked your drawing :D

Answer (score 181):

If you want to merge changes in **SubBranch** to **MainBranch**

1. you should be on MainBranch `git checkout MainBranch`
2. then run merge command  `git merge SubBranch`

Comment: @luckytaxi: Agreed, sometimes less is more

Comment: Can I undo this ?

Comment: @Yohanelly yes,
you can reset git head to any commit.

Comment: `(one the MainBranch)` so what this would mean is git merge `SubBranch`
Where `SubBranch` would be the branch would be the basis of the merge. So any changes to `SubBranch` would be applied to `MainBranch` right? Thanks! I tried it out

Answer (score 5):

Case: If you need to **ignore the merge commit created by default**, follow these steps.

Say, a new feature branch is checked out from master having 2 commits already,

- "Added A" , "Added B"

`Checkout a new feature_branch`

- "Added C" , "Added D"

Feature branch then adds two commits-->

- "Added E", "Added F"

[image]

Now if you want to merge feature_branch changes to master, Do `git merge feature_branch` sitting on the master.

This will add all commits into master branch (4 in master + 2 in feature_branch = total 6) + an extra merge commit something like `'Merge branch 'feature_branch'`' as  the master **is diverged**.

If you really need to ignore this merge commit and add as new commit like `'Integrated feature branch changes into master'`, Run `git merge feature_merge --no-commit`.

With --no-commit, it perform the merge and stop just before creating a merge commit, We will have all the added changes in feature branch now in master and get a chance to create a new merge commit as our own.

**Edit 2023**: You can now have the option to change the merge commit interactively in newer versions of git without specifying the --no-commit option.

Read here for more : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score -2):

To change your subBranch to main

```
git branch -m main <BRANCH>;

git fetch origin;

git branch -u origin/<BRANCH> <BRANCH>;

git remote set-head origin -a
```