# How do I push changes modified in another branch?

Tags: git

I have a BranchA. I did the modifications on BranchA, and wrote a decent comment on it. Then I realized I should do it on a new branch. So I built a new BranchB based on BranchA.

```
git checkout -b BranchB BranchA
```

BranchB has all the changes made in BranchA. But BranchB can be pushed, because BranchB has "nothing" be changed from BranchA.

How do I push BranchB to `origin BranchB`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit my current changes to a different branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944469/how-to-commit-my-current-changes-to-a-different-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this software to manage your branch easily: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

First Commit your code and push it on `BranchB`

```
git commit -m "Your Message"
git push BranchB
```

Then Marge branch `BranchB` into `BranchA`

```
git merge BranchB BranchA
```

[Merging 2 branches together in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404294/merging-2-branches-together-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase origin/master
```

That all your changes to the origin/master would be presented.